# Directed multigraph with numbered edges

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, multigraphs

Let we have a directed multigraph such that or every its vertex the set of edges from this vertex is finite and ordered (in other words, numbered $1,\dots,n$).

I need this construct to describe (depth-first or breath-first) traversing this directed multigraph (where edges are iterated in the above defined order).

What is the term to denote such directed multigraphs with numbered edges?

Comment: "edge-labeled directed multigraph"

Comment: @Casteels: Accordingly my understanding "edge-labeled directed multigraph" may have labels which are not natural numbers, have duplicate labels for two different edges starting in the same vertex, etc. So, I think this is not an answer

Comment: Well, nevertheless, it *is* an edge-labeled directed multigraph." But maybe better is to think of your labels as $n$ colours, and define "outgoing edge-coloured directed multigraph" to mean a directed multigraph with an edge-colouring such that outgoing edges from each vertex receive a different colour.